# Java Error when running getHttpGet method

Tags: java, android

I'm trying the sample code and I get error from this

```
String url = "localhost/newfile.php";
        String resultServer  = getHttpGet(url);
```

It says cannot resolve symbol 'getHttpGet(java.lang.String)'
I'm already added httpclient-4.1.jar and httpcore-4.0.jar
Is there any library file I have to add more ? Thanks for help !

Comment: You need to define a method with the following signature `String getHttpGet(String url)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Loopj http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ it's the most straight forward http response/request library and with a light .jar file. Here is a small example:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://www.yourtargeturl.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // called before request is started
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
        // called when request is retried
    }
});
```

Replace http://www.yourtargeturl.com with the url you want to hit and get the json response.

The onSuccess will give you the response of your GET request. You need to parse the byte[] response like this:

```
String str = new String(response, "UTF-8");
```